# Brother died and I am sole survivor..just found out he has a wallet. How do I go about getting his bit coins I have no info

Tags: bitcoin-core

Brother died I am the sole survivor. I have no info..How do I retreive ..I have death certificate. Thank You
LJF

Comment: Mobile or PC? You need to find out first which wallet software he used

Comment: I'm closing this question .... feel free to edit your question once you have more info or ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

> I have no info..

Without information, you cannot get control of any Bitcoin your brother possessed.

You need some details of his wallet or of his account with a Bitcoin exchange.

> How do I retreive

If he looked after his own money in a Bitcoin wallet on a computer or phone, you need to be able to log in to that device and run the wallet program and enter any password he set on the wallet. He may have kept a note of his wallet's "private key" or its 12, 18 or 24-word "recovery phrase" written down somewhere safe. E.g. on paper or stamped metal in a safe. If so, you can use this information on a different computer to create a new wallet that controls the same money.

If he had an account with a business that looked after his money for him, you'll need to find out the name of that business and his login details. It is possible you would find some details in his old email messages.

> I have death certificate.

That might be of use if his money was in an exchange and you know his account name but not his account password. You or the executor of his estate would need to contact the exchange  directly about this.

---

You will be contacted by people offering to help you. 99% of these will be scammers intending to trick you into trusting them with any details you find, or who will trick you into paying invented recovery fees but who will never give you access to your brother's money. Be very very careful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the public address you can see how much it is currently holding, but there's some additional steps you'll need to review before transferring it somewhere else. I recommend looking into Cryptocurrencies and wallets like found on [Coinbase's FAQ](https://wallet.coinbase.com/faq/) and [Bitcoin.org's](https://bitcoin.org/en/faq).